# Correspondence Theorem in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

(Correspondence Theorem) Suppose $ M\subseteq V$ is a subspace. There is an inclusion preserving bijection $$\{ T : T \text{ is a subspace with} M\subseteq T \subseteq V\} \leftrightarrow \{ \text{subspaces of } V/M\} $$ given by $T\mapsto P_M(T) $.

I am looking for a proof that the function $ T\mapsto P_M ( T) $ is injective and inclusion preserving, including the inverse function. All proofs I have found have used a group theory approach. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any immediate obstacle to simply expanding all the definitions and verifying them. For example, the proof that the map is inclusion-preserving would go like this: suppose that $M\subset T\subset T'\subset V$; we need to prove that $P_M(T)\subset P_M(T')$. So choose $x\in P_M(T)$; we need to prove that $x\in P_M(T')$. And so on.... Where do you encounter difficulties when trying this type of approach?

Comment: The definition of the map $P_M$ is missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $p_M(T) = p_M(S)$. Then if $t \in T$, we have $s_t \in S$ such that $[t] = [s_t]$ or equivalently, $t-s_t \in M$. Thus,

$$
t = (t-s_t) + s_t \in S
$$

because $t-s_t \in M \subset S$. This proves $T \subset S$, and by symmetry we have $T = S$. As for inclusion preserving, there's no linear algebra here: take $f : A \to B$ to be any function between sets. Then both $f$ and taking preimages of $f$ are inclusion preserving operations. (Careful! Strictly speaking, $p_M$ has no inverse in general).

A group theory approach is "inevitable", in the sense that vector spaces are abelian groups with additional structure. Note that we only use the group structure (i.e. the sum of $V$) for the proof. The extension to the context of vector spaces comes when checking that linear functions send subspaces to subspaces and the same for preimages, etc.